# How to add edit in child view of every headerview in expandable list view

Tags: android, adapter

Can anyone tell me how to add an `edit` button in below the all child view of individual `headerview` in `ExpandableListView` and when I click on that edit child button all child values belonging to that header will move on next activity?

Thanks.

```
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (dataarray == null || dataarray.length() == 0) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    ExperienceDetail.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Experience Detail");
            String message = "Experience Detail not retrieved";

            alertDialog.setMessage(message);
            alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
        } else {
                try{
                    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
                    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

                    TextView edit = (TextView) convertView 
                            .findViewById(R.id.cancelbtn); */
                    List<String> hname = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataarray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject dataobject = new JSONObject();
                        dataobject = dataarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        if(dataobject.getString("employer_name")!=null)
                        {
                            listDataHeader.add(dataobject.getString("employer_name")); 
                        // Adding child data

                        hname.add("Employer Name" +" " +" : " +" " +dataobject.getString("employer_name"));
                        hname.add("Designation" +" "+" : " +" " +dataobject.getString("designation"));
                        if(dataobject.getString("from_date")!=null)
                        {
                            hname.add("From Date" +" "+" : " +" " +dataobject.getString("from_date"));
                        }
                        else
                            hname.add("From Date" +" "+" : " +" " +" ");
                        if(dataobject.getString("to_date")!=null)
                            hname.add("To Date" +" "+" : " +" " +dataobject.getString("to_date"));
                        else
                            hname.add("To Date" +" "+" : " +" " +" ");
                        hname.add("Job Location" +" "+" : " +" " +dataobject.getString("job_location"));
                        hname.add("Edit");          
                        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i).toString(), hname); // Header, Child dat
                    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(ExperienceDetail.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

                    // setting list adapter
                    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) 
{
    String title= listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    normal_Child_Count=listDataChild.gett(title).size()
    return normal_Child_Count+1;
}



@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,boolean sLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{

 if(childPosition==normal_Child_Count)
 {
  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.EDIT_LAYOUT, null);//seperate layout for editOption
 }
 else
 {
  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.NORMAL_LAYOUT, null);//seperate layout for normal childs
 }

 if(childPosition==normal_Child_Count)
 {
  Button b=convertView.findViewById(R.id.BUTTON_ID);
  b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
  {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
       {
         //copy relevent data to Bundle
         //Start an activity by intent with bundle      
       }
  });
 }
 else
 {
     //Do normal child item data assigning to view work here
 }

return convertView;      
}
```

Comment: What is the normal_Child_Count+1 is it a variable?

Comment: yup, number of chid items for each group

Comment: in your code you will get the list of strings from the listDatachild Hashmap for each group, so use no.of_items_in_the_list+1 instead of  normal_Child_Count

Comment: okk, i got your point. is this ok.                               int cnt = getChildrenCount(groupPosition); 
        if(childPosition == cnt)
     {
 LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
               .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
         }
         TextView editbtn = (TextView) convertView
           .findViewById(R.id.cancelbtn);
         editbtn.setText("Edit");
        }

Comment: and my children count is like                                         @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

Comment: for normal child do the normal work to display data        if(childPosition == cnt) { use another layout with whatever view you want for edit option and  in onclick listener of that view use bundle and call another activity for editing purpose, thats what i did, it worked for me...

Comment: Hi, i tried as per your suggestion but it display view in other child view as well. can u show me only if(childPosition) condition code only.

Comment: you have to inflate seperate layout for normal children and edit option child, go through the edited code and change your code accordingly